# Updating Google Charts data on form submit

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, charts

I have a Rails app where the Google Charts graphs gather user data from an external server. There is a method in the user model for getting this data from the server, which is called in the users#show controller method.

The `show` method returns a default JSON which I then parse out using `users_helper` methods. These return a JSON-formatted string (not a JSON object) for Google Charts to use.

I am adding functionality to be able to select a date-from and date-to for the data. This is my form (in HAML):

```
= form_tag({:controller=>"manage/users", :action=>"show"}, :id => "datesform", method: :get, remote: true) do
  = text_field_tag :date_from, "", data: {behaviour: "datepicker"}, placeholder: "Date from", :id => "date_from_box"
  = text_field_tag :date_to, "", data: {behaviour: "datepicker"}, placeholder: "Date to", :id => "date_to_box"
  = submit_tag ("Search"), :id => 'chart_submit_dates'
```

Currently, the default timespan is two months (happens only if date_from/date_to params are empty). Upon viewing, this works. The graphs get the right data and everything is rendered.

However, submitting the form does nothing to change the data unless I remove the `remote: true` attribute from the form. When I do that, the entire page refreshes but the graphs are generated with the correct data timeframe specified in the form.

What I'm trying to achieve is for the graph data to update within the page, and then I can call a re-render of the graph when the form is submitted. It sounds like a perfect case for AJAX but everything I've tried hasn't worked (although I am a complete noob to AJAX and javascript, so it's been mostly cut-and-paste from online stuff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. Anyone else with this problem:

I had to make a show.js file along with the show.html file for the graphs. In that js, I had the graph data repopulated, the table remade from the data, and the graph redrawn with that table. In the Users controller, I put in a respond_to block where I indicated both format.html and format.js. After doing this, everything worked. No refresh, the graphs just redrew themselves with the new data after hitting submit on the date fields.